# How to clump store-bought granola?

Tags: snacks, granola

I purchase granola from the store and like to snack on it as an alternative to chips. At the top of the bag, most of the granola are bite-size and easy to pick out. But towards the end of the bag, it is all very small rice-size pieces, and difficult to pick up. Is there a way to take the small pieces and clump them together to make them a bigger size?

Answer (score 1):

this might just work:

let's say there's about a half-cup (or just over 100 ml) of crumbs

1. preheat your oven to 200F (about 90C) with the door closed
2. take a paper towel and tear it in half
3. get one half completely wet with water, but squeeze it out enough so it's not dripping
4. put it in the bag and shake-shake-shake.  this gets a little water more-or-less evenly on the surfaces of the crumbs
5. remove the wet paper towel and shake the clinging crumbs back into the bag
6. dump it all on the dry half of the paper towel and roll it up into a sausage shape
7. set it in the oven on middle of a rack in about the middle of the oven
8. close the oven door and turn off the oven
9. wait at least 4 hours
10. voila, 1 granola roll, i hope

Answer (score -1):

There probably aren't enough crumbs to be worth "clumping". But you could potentially make homemade granola with oats, nuts, dried fruit etc. baked together with some oil and honey or maple syrup. You could use up your crumbs by adding it to your homemade mixture. Personally, though, I wouldn't bother :)